# Storing user input from text field to Parse Database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to store the information a user inputs for the signup page into a parse database, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var fullnameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailAddressField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let userFullname = fullnameField.text
    let userEmailAddress = emailAddressField.text
    let userName = usernameField.text
    let userPassword = passwordField.text


    let User = PFObject(className: "User")
    User["FullName"] = "Example Name"
    User["EmailAddress"] = "JohnDoe@example.com"
    User["Username"] = "Example"
    User["Password"] = "Ilovesmores12345"
    User.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Object has been saved.")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

When a user enters his/her information to the text fields and hit's sign up, I need for the information to save into a parse database for further use on the log in page. I feel like i'm over thinking and making it more complicated, is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

For signing up don't use `user.save` - use `user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock`

Check [this link](https://parse.com/docs//ios/guide#users), it's Parse iOS Guide.

My example, create a button and connect it to `signUpPressed` method. Here's the method.

```
 @IBAction func signUpPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userName = userNameField.text
    let email = emailField.text.lowercaseString
    let password = passwordField.text
    let fullName = fullNameField.text

    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = userName
    user.email = email
    user.password = password

    //for custom fields use default key-value assign
    user["fullName"] = fullName

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String
        // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
      } else {
       // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
      }
    }
  }
```

And I'd recommend to name your object's fields starting with lowercase letter, so that it can't be confused with class names.

Comment: If I click on the link and go to Users > Signing up...how do I connect text fields with those values? Its confusing me a little bit. I just copy pasted that exact code, now how do I connect that to a text field?